# Get telegram channel messages by joinchat link without channel subscription

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Good day.
I have an invite link to the telegram channel in the `joinchat/AAA..` format.

When I interact with telegram through a mobile application, I can see all the messages of this channel even without a subscription.
Is it technically possible to read messages with only an invite link without a subscription?

I am trying to use Telethon in Python.

Comment: the only way is if was a public channel

Comment: @painor but why can i do it with mobile app?

Comment: if you have a link please do share